# Load stylesheets from parent them in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a child theme in WordPress. I do it by adding `style.css` and `function.php` to my `theme-child` directory, but my parent theme has **css** folder that holds the **stylesheet** files.

```
includes/css/main.css
includes/css/main.meanmenu
```

How can I load these files, to customize it in my child-theme?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm once, you had created so far is correct or not by checking the link below . It will describe the creation of child theme

[child theme wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

- A child theme consists of at least one directory (the child theme directory) and two files (style.css and functions.php), which you will need to create:

The child theme directory

```
1. style.css   
2. functions.php
```

If already you had done the above steps.

- You have to select the child theme by dashboard->Appearence->your child theme->activate.
- If you want to edit : Appearence->editor->style.css(child)

Comment: i do it as you say but when i go to style.css in WordPress editor and type css code it dose not  make any change in my website

Answer (score 0):

It might be a typo in your question, or possibly an error with your code, but your question states you added a `function.php` file, but it should be `functions.php` (with an 's').

In your `child-theme/functions.php` file, you should use [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to load your stylesheets.

Add the following code:

```
function xyz_enqueue_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-css-description-1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/css/main.css' );

    // This filename seems incorrect, so change to suit needs
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-css-description-2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/css/main.meanmenu' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xyz_enqueue_parent_css' );
```

The `parent-css-description-1` and `parent-css-description-2` can be anything you want, but they must be unique.

Provided you're using [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) in your theme, these CSS files will be loaded by WordPress for you.

Comment: How do I make sure that there is change happened when I added the previous code

Comment: @user3680224 When you view the source of your website, you should see the CSS files listed in the `<head>...</head>` tag. Presumably, the parent theme CSS files would also change the appearance of the website in an obvious way.

Comment: i look like that                                                                                         href=http://localhost:8080/project/website/wp-content/themes/parent-theme-name/includes/css/main.css"

Comment: You can override the CSS of your parent theme by adding corresponding CSS to child theme.